# I tried downloading a file using its mime type in react js but when the pdf gets downloaded it has no content just the correct no. of pages

Tags: reactjs, axios, download, mime-types, mime

> This is the function to download it getting the mime type along with other values from the api call for each document in the parent element

```
  const downloadDocument = (handleString, mimeType, typeName) => {
    var docInfo = {
      handleString,
      mimeType,
      typeName,
    };
    webServiceAgent.PolicyDashboard.downloadFullfillment(docInfo, {
      responseType: "blob",
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("success calling downloadFullfillment");
        const blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/pdf" });

        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.download = typeName;
        console.log(link);
        link.click();

        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
      console.log("success calling downloadFullfillment",policyDocs);
  };

      
<button className="btn textWhite bgBlue" onClick={() => downloadDocument(item?.handleString, item?.mimeType, item?.typeName)}>                             {myPolicyContentVariables?.downloadButtonLabel}
</button>
```